# How to limit a website's viewport height with html, especially for desktop users?

Tags: html, web, responsive-design, viewport

Is there a way to limit a website's viewport height with html, especially on desktop/alternatively is there a way to create a viewport on a page that displays the page of another website url within the viewport?

I want my webpage to have a limited height, regardless of the user's screen size.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do something like iframe?     >>>>>> 
[w3school-iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use container on everything after body tag and specify it width/height using media queries.